# How to generate shadow around custom shaped vector drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have custom vector drawable which is used as separator of 2 layouts. These 2 layouts are rectangular shape so I can make LinearLayout parent around them and generate 9-patch png with exact dp width and height + corner radius. But this separator has custom shape. How to generate shadow for this component to fit and match those right and left layout shadows?

Website for generating rectangular shadows --> [here](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

My layout separator with missing shadow:

[image]